# trying to get list of list from django in javascript as data for csv but quotes shown in html number

Tags: javascript, python, django

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

/* csv_list:  list of list got from django index function (views.py) eg:[['abc','1'],['xyz','0']] */

```
    var data = {{csv_list}};

    function genrate_csv() {
        var csv = 'Tweet, Polarity\n';
        data.forEach(function(row) {
                csv += row.join(',');
                csv += "\n";
        });

        console.log(csv);
        var new_elm = document.createElement('a');
        new_elm.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(csv);
        new_elm.target = '_blank';
        new_elm.download = 'data.csv';
        new_elm.click();
    }
 </script>
```

**Error showing html code for quote**
[image: error showing html code for quote]

```
 django code: (views.py)

 def index(request):
   if request.method=="POST" and request.POST.get('query') != "":
     tweet_list =    
  script.tweets(request.POST.get('query'),request.POST.get('numtweets'))
    pos,neg,net,csv_list = script.analysis(tweet_list)
    context = {
        'tweet_list' : tweet_list,
        'csv_list' : csv_list,   #passed the list of list
        't': len(tweet_list)
    }
    return render(request,"index.html",context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, pass data between Python and Javascript using a proper data interchange format - ie JSON - rather than relying on the similarities between the syntaxes.

And secondly, you need to mark your data as safe in the template to avoid autoescaping. So:

```
context = {
    'tweet_list' : tweet_list,
    'csv_list' : json.dumps(csv_list),
    't': len(tweet_list)
}
return render(request,"index.html",context)
```

...

```
var data = JSON.parse('{{ csv_list|safe }}');
```

Although I must say overall I'm not sure why you want to generate this CSV in Javascript, rather than allowing the user to download it directly from the backend as a file.